# can't move my nav bar to the center/change its size and the page overflows

Tags: html, css, node.js, frontend

So I can't change the size of my nav bar. I can't move it to the center either. Also I can scroll my page down and to the sides even though I set the body width and height to 100vw and 100vh. Can someone help?

My Code:

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline block;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 108px;
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 500px;
    display: inline block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="KinoWorld homepage" content="html/css file">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Stuff</h1>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What `navbar`? Where? Are you referring to `div` *search*?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you set the body to a width of `100vw` doesn't limit child elements to `100vw`. You'll either want to set `overflow-x: hidden` on the body, or better yet, use appropriate styling on child elements.

For your div, try to avoid using pixel widths, but if you must, set a `max-width: 100%;` so they won't overflow their parent. You also have a typo `display: inline block;` needs to by hyphenated. Though you don't need to make this element an `inline-block;`, it's fine as a `block` level element.

Also, the body by default will be `100vw`, you can set that as a `max-width` value which will aide if it's framed in (like with the snippets below), but usually it isn't necessary.

If you have a small page, and want it to be "full page no matter what", set it's `min-height: 100vh`, there's rarely a reason to limit it's total height to `100vh`.

The simplest way to center an `inline` or `inline-block` element (your search input) is to set `text-align: center;` on the parent. Also note that semantically, you should use `<input type="search">` for search form elements.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
    background-color: black;
    max-width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: inline block;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 108px;
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 2000px;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="KinoWorld homepage" content="html/css file">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

         <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Stuff</h1>
        <div class="search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search..">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```